# Use Rails’ form_for but set custom classes, attributes on <form> element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`form_for` seems to ignore any 'extra' attributes like a `data-foo` attribute or `class` passed as `options` in its second argument.

```
= form_for @user, {:url => 'foo', :class => 'x', 'data-bar' => 'baz' } do |f|
  # ...
```

The output is a `<form>` tag with no `x` class or `data-bar` attribute.

What’s the fix?

Or, how can I grab a `FormBuilder` instance without using `form_for`?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Use the `:html` hash:

```
= form_for @user, :html => {:class => 'x', 'data-bar' => 'baz'} do |f|
```

Or

```
= form_for @user, html: {class: 'x', data: { bar: 'baz' } } do |f|
```

Comment: I found that this doesn't work: `= form_for @user, :html => {'class' => 'x'} do |f|`. `class` should be a symbol instead of string.

Answer (score 11):

Rails 4.0.3, Ruby 2.1.0p0  -> this worked for me =>

```
<%= form_for(@contact, :html => {:class => 'form_height'}) do |f| %><% if     @contact.errors.any? %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but was puzzled that another form elsewhere in my app was working fine.

I realized that I had accidentally added a **form_for** inside another **form_for** which once removed cured the problem.

Secondly, I should add that this syntax works for me in Rails 4.2:

```
<%= form_for @type, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
```

I find it preferable to the punctuation-soup of the other answers here (which were perhaps based on an older Rails version).

Answer (score 1):

On mostly helpers, the last arg is a hash of html options for the element.

```
= form_for @user, :html => {:class => 'x', 'data-bar' => 'baz'} %>
```

You can also check other alternatives in the documentation [ActionsView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above with no luck but found a solution.
I'm using rails 4.1.6.

This didn't work

```
= form_for @user, :html => {:class => 'x', 'data-bar' => 'baz'} %>
```

This did

```
= form_for @user, html: {:class => 'x', 'data-bar' => 'baz'} %>
```

notice the difference with the html option, hope this helps

Comment: Wow, really? those should be exactly equivalent. You can reproduce this? Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @Alan H. Using Ruby 2.1.3p242 

    `= form_for(:user, :url => login_path, html: {:class => 'login_form'}) do |f| %>`

This was the only way that my code would apply the class, otherwise it was just ignoring it.

Comment: Those two lines are exactly identical. Guessing you forgot to save in between?

Comment: I know, they should be. For me it just wasn't working though. Saving wasn't the issue.