# Adding a custom class for form_for in Ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying out development on Ruby on Rails and I am creating a form using form_for helper:

```
 <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) , :html => {:class => "formsignin"} do |f| %>
```

I am trying to add my own custom class formsignin but this does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Rails’ form\_for but set custom classes, attributes on <form> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144624/use-rails-form-for-but-set-custom-classes-attributes-on-form-element)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:html` option is an argument to `form_for` helper, you've closed `form_for` method call too early!  Reference documentation for [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Try the following:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path, html: {class: "formsignin"}) do |f| %>
```